# Storing values in an array with wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

So I am trying to create a wordpress plugin that stores all the dates of posts written in a certain month. So if there were posts published on the 10th, 12th and 18th of this month, I want to store those dates '10', '12' and '18' in the array `$stack[]`. Im new to php and so I can't figure out why this isn't storing the dates in the array:

```
// The Query
$themonth = date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
query_posts('cat=4&month=' . $themonth );
// The Loop
$stack = array();
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
$stack[] = the_time('j');
endwhile;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while into this:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : 
    the_post();
    $stack[the_time('j')] = get_the_content();
endwhile;
```

Comment: This seems to store the content of the post inside the array. I don't need to store the content, just the day of the month that the post was created.

Comment: So, ignore the content and just use the day in the key of the array!